# Does anyone know of a good technique to combine regex expressions using python?

Tags: python, regex

I an new to programming but have done extensive searching and I cannot seem to find anything to put me on the right track.I have a large list of regex's. I need to find a method to combine these if possible. The regex's I have are numbers only

For example my list looks like this

```
832118[0-3]
832118[7-8]
832119[0-1]
832119[4-6]
832119[8-9]
8321206
832120[0-4]
832120[8-9]
```

My desired output would look like this

```
832118[0-37-8]
832119[0-14-68-9]
832120[0-468-9]
```

Thanks for any tips you can provide!

> Blockquote

Comment: Are you sure regexes are the right tool to use here?

Comment: Yes. I am using these expressions in a third party system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a defaultdict and this simple regex: [`(\d+)\[(\d+-\d+)\]`](https://regex101.com/r/STVFRB/1)

If you want to match a format other than `Numbers[Numbers-Numbers]` you will have to change the regular expression.

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict
dct = defaultdict(str)
data = ['832118[0-3]', '832118[7-8]', '832119[0-1]', '832119[4-6]', '832119[8-9]', '8321206', '832120[0-4]', '832120[8-9]']
for line in data:
    mtch = re.findall(r"(\d+)\[(\d+-\d+)\]", line)
    if mtch:
        dct[mtch[0][0]] += mtch[0][1]

for i, j in dct.items():
    print(i, '['+ j + ']')
```

Output:

```
832118 [0-37-8]
832120 [0-48-9]
832119 [0-14-68-9]
```

Comment: This is very close to what I am looking to do. The only issue I see is it did not catch the number 8321206 and add it to the expression like this 832120[0-468-9]. I will keep playing with it. Thanks very much for your reply!